# gui Information do i from wp7 xap file?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ui-automation, testautomationfx, wp7test

I'm a student in South Korea interested in becoming a programmer.
I'm currently interested in making a software to automatize windows application testing.
I have a question regarding this matter
Is it possible to obtain the UI information of Wp7 in the same way as UI Automation that .net supports?
gui Information do i from wp7 xap file?

ex)gui name = txt_name, gui Property = TextBox <-- This Information

Answer (score 1):

Check out WP7 Test framework : https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework

I don't think there is support to do that. If you don't have the source code you can:

- download the xap
- extract the xap using 7zip
- and decompile using DisSharpF to get the source to retrieve id's

Comment: I think you could fairly easily add support for that sort of information using a visualtreehelper to navigate all the items in the tree and then using reflection to work out the required properties.